# webpack process.env.NODE_ENV undefined

Tags: webpack, vuejs3, nodeenv

I have the webpack.config below. I'm using a vue plugin (vue-fusioncharts) that's running javascript that looks for "process.env.NODE_ENV !== 'production'", and from what I can tell putting a break point there, the "process" object is null at that point. So wondering what I'm doing wrong in my webpack.config where process object isn't available globally as I thought it would be. I'm setting the "process.env.NODE_ENV" the way I see in examples. This is vue 3 project with webpack and I'm running "npm run watch" and then debugging locally, trying to get rid of this warning..

Warning message (what I'm trying to resolve):

[image]

Offending code where process is null:

[image]

webpack.config:

```
const path = require('path');
const webpack = require('webpack');

const { CleanWebpackPlugin } = require('clean-webpack-plugin');
const MiniCssExtractPlugin = require('mini-css-extract-plugin');
const { VueLoaderPlugin } = require("vue-loader");

const srcPath = path.resolve(__dirname, './src');
const stylePath = path.resolve(srcPath, './styles');
const bldPath = path.resolve('../BlahApp/wwwroot/dist');

module.exports = {
    //devtool: 'source-map',
    entry: {
        master: path.resolve(srcPath, 'index.js'),
        style: `${stylePath}/style.css`
    },
    resolve: {
        alias: {
            'vue': 'vue/dist/vue.esm-bundler.js'
        }
    },
    mode: 'production',
    watch: true,
    module: {
        rules: [
            {
                test: /\.scss$/,
                use: [{ loader: 'style-loader' },
                      { loader: 'css-loader' },
                        {
                            loader: 'postcss-loader',
                            options: {
                                postcssOptions: {
                                    plugins: [ require('autoprefixer') ]
                                    }
                                }                       
                        },
                    { loader: 'sass-loader' }]
            },
            {
                exclude: /(node_modules|bower_components)/,
                include: srcPath,
                test: /\.js$/,
                use: [{ loader: 'babel-loader' }]
            },
            {
                test: /\.(woff(2)?|ttf|eot|svg)(\?v=\d+\.\d+\.\d+)?$/,
                use: [
                    {
                        loader: 'file-loader',
                        options: {
                            name: '[name].[ext]',
                            publicPath: './fonts/',
                            outputPath: './fonts/',
                            esModule: false
                        }
                    }
                ]
            },
            {
                test: /\.css$/,
                use: [MiniCssExtractPlugin.loader, 'css-loader']
            },
            {
                test: /\.vue$/,
                loader: 'vue-loader'
            },
            {
                test: /\.(png|jpg|jpeg|gif)$/,
                use: [
                    {
                        loader: 'file-loader',
                        options: {
                            name: '[name].[ext]',
                            outputPath: './images/',
                            publicPath: './images/',
                            esModule: false
                        }
                    }
                ]
            }
        ]
    },
    optimization: {
        splitChunks: {
            cacheGroups: {
                vendors: {
                    chunks: 'all',
                    name: 'vendor',
                    test: /[\\/]node_modules[\\/]/
                }
            }
        },
    },
    output: {
        filename: '[name].min.js',
        chunkFilename: '[name].min.js',
        globalObject: 'this',
        path: `${bldPath}`,
        publicPath: '/dist/'
    },
    plugins: [
        new CleanWebpackPlugin({
            cleanOnceBeforeBuildPatterns: [`${bldPath}/**`],
            dry: false,
            verbose: true,
            dangerouslyAllowCleanPatternsOutsideProject: true
        }),
        new VueLoaderPlugin(),
        new MiniCssExtractPlugin({
            filename: '[name].min.css'
        }),
        new webpack.DefinePlugin({
            'process.env' : {
                'NODE_ENV' : '"production"'
            }
        })      
    ]
};
```

Package.json:

```
{
  "name": "blah-app.ui",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "description": "BlahApp.UI",
  "author": {
    "name": ""
  },
  "scripts": {
    "build": "webpack --color --progress",
    "watch": "webpack --color --progress --watch"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.14.8",
    "@vue/compiler-sfc": "^3.1.5",
    "autoprefixer": "^10.3.1",
    "babel-loader": "^8.2.2",
    "clean-webpack-plugin": "^4.0.0-alpha.0",
    "css-loader": "^6.2.0",
    "expose-loader": "^3.0.0",
    "file-loader": "^6.2.0",
    "mini-css-extract-plugin": "^2.1.0",
    "node-sass": "^6.0.1",
    "postcss": "^8.3.6",
    "postcss-loader": "^6.1.1",
    "sass-loader": "^12.1.0",
    "style-loader": "^3.2.1",
    "url-loader": "^4.1.1",
    "vue-loader": "^16.4.1",
    "webpack": "^5.48.0",
    "webpack-cli": "^4.7.2"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@fortawesome/fontawesome-free": "^5.15.3",
    "@vuelidate/core": "^2.0.0-alpha.22",
    "@vuelidate/validators": "^2.0.0-alpha.19",
    "axios": "^0.21.1",
    "bootstrap": "^4.5.2",
    "core-js": "^3.16.0",
    "fusioncharts": "^3.17.0",
    "lodash": "^4.17.21",
    "moment": "^2.29.1",
    "popper.js": "^1.16.1",
    "source-map-loader": "^3.0.0",
    "tabulator-tables": "^4.9.3",
    "tippy.js": "^6.3.1",
    "vue": "^3.1.5",
    "vue-final-modal": "^3.4.0",
    "vue-fusioncharts": "^3.1.0",
    "vue-next-select": "^2.8.0"
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Issue seems to have been vue-fusioncharts package, I upgraded to 3.2.0 (vue 3 compatible) and the message went away.

Also note for webpack 4.0+ you don't need to use the "webpack.DefinePlugin", you just use the mode property of webpack (https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/deployment.html)